# What brachot on date honey?

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits

What bracha rishona and bracha acharona should be said on date honey?

Comment: Did it pop up on Google when searching "date honey brachot"? What did you find lacking that you need to ask for further clarification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OU's site](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos-2-mishneh-torah/527-brachos-soup-sugar/) (citing [Rambam Berakhot 8:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927676/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-Eight.htm)) says that by default you should say *shehakol,* unless certain conditions are met:

> *Shehakol* is recited over the honey of dates. Nevertheless, if one crushes dates manually, removes the pits and makes them into a dough-like substance, the *bracha* is *Borei pri ho’eitz* beforehand and the *bracha* that includes the three themes of bentching (i.e., *al ho’eitz)* after.

This ruling is based on [Berakhot 38a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=38&format=pdf):

> .ואמר מר בר רב אשי האי דובשא דתמרי מברכין עלויה שהכל נהיה בדברו. מ"ט זיעה בעלמא הוא
>
> Mar son of R. Ashi also said: Over honey of the date-palm we say, *'by whose word all things exist'.*  What is the reason? — Because it is merely moisture [of the tree]. <sub>[Soncino](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_38.html) translation</sub>

Based on this argument it can be said that the *berakha achrona* is *borei nefashot.* However, this view was later contested by בה"ג, as it is discussed in this [article](http://www.kikar.co.il/amp/109971) (see also [Pesachim 24b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=24b&format=pdf) on the other hand). In contrast, Rambam's ruling was confirmed in [Orach Chayim 202:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%97).

Comment: If you can, please add to this answer what the bracha Achrona should be. The quote you have states the bracha achrona if you make the "dough".

Comment: @DanF Indeed, but first I'd like to understand the logic from בבלי

Comment: @DanF If the *bracha rishona* is *Shehakol*, the *bracha Achrona* would be *borei nefashos*. AFAIK there wouldn't be any other possibilities.

Comment: @DanF Check it now. I suppose it was important to understand the argument of the Gemarah.